# How do I view mouse-over text with an iPad?

Tags: ipad, mouse

Some websites have text that appears when you hover over an image or link with the mouse cursor.  Touching the screen of an iPad does not appear to activate this text.

Is there a way to see mouse-over text on an iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [hint at MacWorld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100404045906105) recommends a bookmarklet that you can install that allows you to tap an image to display its alt text.

Try that - works great for me on my iPhone.